# Click button if the URL matches with JS

Tags: javascript

There's a "Book Now" tab on a website. when you click it, it opens a form. I need to make the button open automatically if the URL is `www.example.com/en/?emailer`. I tried this:

```
if (window.location.href == "http://www.example/en/?emailer") {
  document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[0].click();
}
```

The thing is that if I paste this code on the page in the console, it works. However when I added it to the header.php WordPress file, it's not working.

Any idea why it works in the console and not in the `<head>`? Can someone tell me how can I get this done?

Note: the tab has the class 'tab' as seen in the code section.

Comment: `when I added it to the header.php WordPress file, it's not working.` It sounds like you're executing this logic too early; ie. before the DOM is fully loaded. I'd suggest placing this just before the `</body>` tag, or in a document `load` event handler

Comment: Oh I suspected this, Let me try

Comment: also that is not jQuery.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: it would be more easy i think with document.ready() function in jquery. \

Comment: @AlexiAmni Just wrap it in a `(function(){ xyz })()` or `DOMContentLoader` listener. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: @MarkBaijens yes yes I know but in case there's a jquery fix. that would work too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so I added it to the footer.php file and it's still not working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    if (window.location.href == "http://www.example/en/?emailer") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[0].click();
    }
});
```

Comment: It should work in header as well as end of body before `</body>` tag. If it doesn't work try checking the console of the browser for javascript errors.

Comment: also you need to add this code in `<script> {code} </script>` tag if you are adding it in html

Answer (score 0):

You should use onreadystatechange for that

```
$(document).on('readystatechange', function() {
    if (window.location.href == "http://www.example/en/?emailer") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[0].click();
    }
});
```

Comment: So I tried that and for some reason all the other scripts on the page stopped working :/ I added it to the header

Answer (score -1):

The issue is, in fact, that the DOM tree is not fully built by the time your script is being executed. A quick fix would be a simple

```
setTimeout(function () {
    if (window.location.href == "http://www.example/en/?emailer") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[0].click();
    }
}, 0);
```

Like that, you await the next tick in the event loop, by when the DOM tree is setup.

Comment: I don't think setTimeout is good practice in 2018, where you have special events for catching this type of problems

Comment: So I tried that and for some reason all the other scripts on the page stopped working :/ I added it to the header